# How to export tab-delimited text file from Python (with spesifications)

Tags: python, export

I'm trying to export a data frame from Python. How can I do it?
I have already imported the data to Python.

[image: df]

I need to create a tab-delimited text file like this:

[image: desired_output]

**Spesifications:** no column names, no tabs/blanks.

The data is here: https://github.com/gungorMetehan/TAP/blob/main/Data/data.xlsx

In R, this can be done as follows:

```
write.table(data_new, "C:\\Users\\blablabla", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F, sep = "")
```